# Same query resulting in different outputs in Hive vs Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Hive 2.3.6-mapr

Spark v2.3.1

I am running same query:

```
select count(*)
from TABLE_A a 
left join TABLE_B b 
    on a.key = c.key 
    and b.date > '2021-01-01' 
    and date_add(last_day(add_months(a.create_date, -1)),1) < '2021-03-01'  
where cast(a.TIMESTAMP as date) >= '2021-01-20' 
    and cast(a.TIMESTAMP as date) < '2021-03-01'
```

But getting 1B rows as output in hive, while 1.01B in spark-sql.

By some initial analysis, it seems like all the extra rows in spark are having `timestamp` column as  2021-02-28 00:00:00.000000.

Both the TIMESTAMP and create_date columns have data type *string*.
What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you one possibility, but I need more information.

If you drop an external table, the data remains and spark can read it, but the metadata in Hive says it doesn't exist and doesn't read it.

That's why you have a difference.